# error in node constructor for Linked-list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

i'm trying to make a LinkedList of ints and for that i created a Node class. but the compiler constantly gives me the same error. i searched all over the web and the answers i found didn't work, or i did not understand them.

the error is the following:
line 51: new types may not be defined in a return type
line 51: return type specification for constructor invalid

all 4 constructors have the same problem, the error in line 51 is just the first one of the four.

here is my Node class with all it has. i didn't copy the getters and setters because they have no errors, and the code is semi-obvious.

thanks a lot. 
Andy

```
class Node{

private:
    int val;
    Node* pPrv;
    Node* pNxt;

public:
    Node();
    Node(Node&);
    Node(int);    
    Node(int, Node*, Node*);

    void setVal(int auxVal);
    void setPrv(Node* auxPrv);
    void setNxt(Node* auxNxt);

    int getVal();
    Node* getPrv();
    Node* getNxt();
}

Node::Node(){ //this is line 51
    val = 0;
    pPrv = NULL;
    pNxt = NULL;
}

Node::Node(Node &node2){ //this line has exactly the same error
    val = node2.getVal();
    pPrv = node2.getPrv();
    pNxt = node2.getNxt();
}

Node::Node(int valAux){ //so does this one
    val = valAux;
    pPrv = NULL;
    pNxt = NULL;
}

Node::Node(int valAux, Node* prvAux, Node* nxtAux){ //and also this one
    val = valAux;
    pPrv = prvAux;
    pNxt = nxtAux;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon `;` after your class declaration.

Comment: By the way, be careful with your copy-constructor. Copying a node can lead to nasty things happening if you remove a node from the list, and you expect the `pPrv` and `pNxt` to be valid. If you remove the node pointed to by `pNxt`, the original will be updated, but the copy will still have its old `pNxt  pointer, now pointing to a removed node.

Comment: Do you write this list only for exercise? You can use `list` or `deque` from standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot tp place a semicolon after the class definition.

In this case the compiler considers the declaration of the class above constructor `Node()`

```
class Node{
//...
}
Node::Node(){
    val = 0;
    pPrv = NULL;
    pNxt = NULL;
}
```

as its return type.